# Why is "great" on the decline?

Tags: word-choice

Consider this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=great&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgreat%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgreat%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGreat%3B%2Cc0). Why is the word "great" declining so rapidly. It seems to me such a common word that would be used everywhere.

[image]

Comment: "Why" questions are notoriously difficult to answer, if not impossible.

Comment: Please explain why you think its use is declining "rapidly". It is still used more than "big" and a lot more than "fantastic". It is used a lot more than common words like "hand" or "table". What causes you to wonder or worry about the fate of "great"?

Comment: @oerkelens - what worries the OP is clearly the sloping curve in the Ngram graph which,  if accurate, reveals that “great” usage frequency is now about  one third of what it used to be at the beginning of the 19th century.   Nothing   to worry about...I suppose.

Comment: I suspect it has declined in popularity as the language has gotten more informal. If you play around with wildcard searches, it looks like the most common phrase that used "great" in the early 1800s was *a great number of*. Today that phrase feels a little bit stuffy for ordinary use. Circa 1800, *a great many* was more than fifty times as popular as the phrase *a lot of*, but by c. 2000 this had reversed so that *a lot of* was almost forty times as popular as *a great number of* (and actually more than twice as common as *a great number of* was at its peak).

Comment: Make English [use] *great* again!

Comment: @1006a Why do you think language has become more informal?

Comment: That's just great.

Comment: More of a problem that it's used too much in recent years, when the writer just means 'good', or 'fair'.  Great inflation, I think it's called.

Comment: I checked several phrases containing the word great—"a great many," "a great deal of," "how great," "so great," and "great God"—and the only one that produces a sharp continuous decline is "so great." See this [Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+great+many%2Ca+great+deal+of%2Chow+great%2Cso+great%2C+great+God&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20great%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20great%20deal%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20great%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20great%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20God%3B%2Cc0). I have no explanation.

Comment: Actually "the great" and "a great" have dropped sharply since 1900, but were fairly stable over the preceding century, as [this version of the Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+great+many%2Ca+great+deal+of%2Chow+great%2Cso+great%2Cgreat+God%2Cthe+great%2C+a+great&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20great%20many%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20great%20deal%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20great%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cso%20great%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreat%20God%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20great%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20great%3B%2Cc0) indicates.